# Macbook Pro 2012 with 3 partitions on Fusion Drive

Tags: partitioning, macbook-pro, fusion-drive

I have a Fusion Drive that has 2 partitions on it (the max that Disk Utility allows).  The partitions are Mac OSX and Ubuntu. The OSX partition is ~900GB and the Ubuntu partition is ~100GB.

It is safe to use a Live CD to partition the 100GB partition so I can install Windows on it? Are there any drawbacks of doing this, considering Disk Utility does not allow it?